# Adapt result of one row to other rows

Tags: mysql, case

How can I can write the query this way, that the result of the CASE WHEN - statement is adapted to every row. So that in every row the result will be 5.  Thank you very much!

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(`Person` CHAR(4),
 `Apples` INT(1),
 `Tomatoes` INT(1),
 `Result` INT(1)
  );

 INSERT INTO DATA
 (Person, Apples, Tomatoes)
  VALUES ('Mark' , 1, 2),
    ('Sepp',  2, 3),
    ('Carl',  3, 1);

 UPDATE  DATA
 SET `Result` = CASE WHEN (`Person` =  'Sepp') THEN (`Apples` + `Tomatoes`)  END;
```

[Table of result as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLXxC.jpg)

[SQL fiddle demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/668353/1)

Comment: I'd go for `UPDATE DATA SET Result=5`. You want every column to have a fixed value so no need for complex rules

Comment: @LelioFaieta I don't think the 5 represents a fixed value, but rather the result of adding Sepps apples and tomatoes.

Comment: @jpw i agree. But if you see the desired result it is always 5 and the result per row is never 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all rows to get the value from Sepps row you can do it using a subquery.

The "normal" way would be to do this:

```
UPDATE DATA
SET Result = (SELECT Apples + Tomatoes FROM DATA WHERE Person =  'Sepp')
```

But this will most likely give you an error with MySQL (*can't specify target table for update*) and a workaround is to introduce another level in the query which forces a temporary table to be used, like this:

```
UPDATE DATA
 SET Result = (
   SELECT Value FROM (
     SELECT Apples + Tomatoes AS Value 
     FROM DATA WHERE Person =  'Sepp'
   ) t
 );
```

Comment: I see that your code is working in the SQL fiddle. But when i build it exactly this way with in my database, I get the message you already mentioned: "You can´t specify target table...for update in FROM clause?

Comment: @Sven Did you try the first or second version in my answer. Just to be clear: the second is the correct on and the first will not work. For MySQL that is.

Comment: @Sven Ok, that's odd then; like you observed it works fine in the fiddle, so I really don't understand why it is not working for you. Sorry.

Comment: @Sven You could try this variant which should work too: `update data t1, (SELECT Apples + Tomatoes AS Value FROM data WHERE Person =  'Sepp') t2 set t1.result = t2.value;`

Comment: Thanks jpw. This code works. But the query runs now til 40 min. Perhaps i better create some extra tables to avoid such sub-queries...

Comment: @Sven Yeah, I'd imagine this won't perform well at all; it's essentially a cross (or cartesian) join; a better much faster option would be to first do the query that does the calculation for the result column and store that in a variable, and then do the update using that variable in the set part of the update statement. You might want to look into user variables in the documentation.